# Using a batch file, I need to add a reference path to each project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file, build-automation

I have a visual studio .vdproj project that I need to build which I can quite simply do using devenv in a batch file. Before that however, I would like to add a reference path to each individual project through that same batch file (as part of my efforts to auto build the entire project).

I am a complete novice at VS and batch files but I figure this is achievable.

Comment: Not exactly answering your question, but have you looked at NAnt?  Ant provides at least the sandbox for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it answers the question the way that you wanted but you could use a CI server such as Jenkins: http://jenkins-ci.org/   and then you wouldn't need to figure out how to create a multi-build .bat script.  Each project could still have it's own independent build script and Jenkins can handle building them as a group.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a deployment project which does just that, the thing is every project (before building the deployment project) needs a reference path added manually which I am trying to automate. Sorry if I'm not making sense, let me know if you need clarification

Comment: Yeah, your going to need to clarify a bit more than that.  What do you mean by "reference path"?

Comment: I have build dependencies that reference a folder on my machine. So to do this manually, I right click each project file  that requires those dependencies in visual studio, click properties, reference paths, and I add the folder I want. How would I automate this process?

Comment: Hmm. It sounds like that right-click action you are doing is basically modifying a project config in the back-end, perhaps an .xml file?  If its an .xml file, you can modify it using "xmlstarlet" in your script, or you can use Powershell, which has xml editing capability.